# Understanding ntpd entry in syslog

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, syslog

Does anyone know what this entry in syslog means:

`static1 ntpd[2397]: 2a00:xxxx:xxxx:239::2 interface 2a01:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:fe70:a40c -> (null)`

(I've replaced some of the values with xxxx)

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a failure to sync with an ipv6 ntp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the NTP peer at 2a00:xxxx:xxxx:239::2 used to be available via the network interface identified by the address 2a01:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:fe70:a40c, but it is no longer believed to be reachable by any interface.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why the error message couldn't just say something like this?